# Unable to access web api from client

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Running `dotnet project.dll` from command prompt starts the process listening on the port.

I type `http://localhost:[PORT]/[CONTROLLER]` on the server I get the correct JSON data.
However, when I type `http://[IP_ADDRESS]:[PORT]/[CONTROLLER]` on the client I get connection timeout.

[image]

Using browser for both.

Comment: I faced the same once with Golang server. The reason I couldn't get any response from server in my client was that I had to use IP adress `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for some reason. I see that you've specified that you do the same already, but maybe try the opposisite? `localhost` instead of ip?

Comment: Is that port open on your server? From what I understood, you're trying to access from a different machine.

Comment: Oh, if you mean access your server which is running on remote machine, then yeah, check firewall and other configuration first. It may be Docker misconfiguration for example

Comment: @Andrew port on firewall is allowed for inbound and outbound. Port was used by another process which is successfully accessed. However, for dotnet, it always fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think your doing something wrong I want to say you some checks do these to be sure (I almost sure one these checks fix your problem)

1. check your port ,or maybe used in other process and you can check it with post man for being sure.
2. You can change your port and test it with other port.
3. Check urls and your routes

One of these check fix’s your problem.